# JQuery $('select').change has multiple values

Tags: jquery

I'm new with Javascript and JQuery, so, I probably did something wrong and it causes my issue, explainations are below.

I am generating options for a select comparing to a first select value. When both options are choosen, the user has to press the submit button, and I'm receiving the right file content from PHP. But there's an issue : if the user is changing multiple times the dateChoiceSelect value, multiple values are stored in its .var(), and when these values are submitted, the PHP code is runned more than one time, how can I cope with it ?

Here's the code :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#projectChoice').submit(function()
    {
        let valSelectProject=$('#projectChoiceSelect').val();
        $('#dateChoiceSelect').change(function()
        {

            let valSelectDate=$('#dateChoiceSelect').val();
            let dataToPHP = {choosenDate : valSelectDate, choosenProject 
            :valSelectProject};
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"js/json/pointsWhereDateExists.php",
                data:dataToPHP,
                success:function(returnedFromPHP)
                {
                    let listOfPoints = JSON.parse(returnedFromPHP);
                    $('#pointChoiceSelect').children().remove();
                    listOfPoints.forEach(function(element)
                    {
                        $('#pointChoiceSelect').append($('<option>',{value : 
                        element, text : element}));
                    }) 
                }
             });
             $('#pointChoice').submit(function()
             {
                 valSelectPoint = $('#pointChoiceSelect').val();
                 console.log(valSelectPoint);
                 let valFormat = $('#pointChoice 
                 input[name="choosenFormat"]:checked').val();
                 let dataToPHP = {choosenProject : valSelectProject, choosenDate : valSelectDate, choosenPoint : valSelectPoint, choosenFormat : valFormat};

                 $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"js/json/getAVGFileContent.php",
                    data:dataToPHP,
                    success:function(returnedFromPHP)
                    {
                        console.log(JSON.parse(returnedFromPHP));   
                    }
                 });

                 return false;
             });
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: move the point choice binding outside the project choice submit binding - you only need to bind once, not every time you submit the project choice

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly